# How to safely add tags in html document using php

Tags: php, html

I have an html code saved in a database. I want to convert specific words (for example: school, books, chock) into links ( tags) and I want the conversion to be safe.

One possible way to do that is to strip all tags first, so that I will not add a link where it is not supposed to be. But in this case I will loose the formatting and I don't want that.

To clarify the problem I will show you some examples for a problematic code, where an error will occur if I try to change "books" into "books:

```
1.   <div class="books">lorem ipsum dolor....
2.   <a href = "http://www.example.com">all of the books in the store</a>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should be able to do a regex replace with some rules to prevent it from converting words that are part of already existing tags. Personally I'd write a small state machine instead as it would be clearer and easier for this - the regular expression could become quite convoluted I think. I'm not big on regex or state machines in PHP however, so hopefully someone can give you more clear answer. :)

Comment: I am sure this can be done with regular expression... Any regular expression expert out there that wants to help?

Comment: Hummm... state machine... that will be easier to write, but it will be slower. I will try to answer with a machine.... Wait a while.

Comment: Yes, however I think it can be really hard with a regex that 1) detects if the word is part of an attribute and 2) is in between <a> tags.

Comment: Attribute is easy, <A> tags are harder.

Comment: On second though, state machines are too hard to explain in words. I have put in an answer using string search instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way to do it using just string search and replace.

```
for each word,
  do a search in the html code.
  for each found word,

    if there there is a "<" somewhere on the left side of the found word then

      if there is no ">" between the closest "<" and the start of the found word then
        The word is in a html tag? Ignore the word.
      end if
    end if

    if there is a "<a " somewhere on the left side of the word then
      if there is no "</a>" between the closest "<a " and the start of the found word then
        The word is already a link? Ignore the word.
      end if
    end if

    if none of the conditions above matches then
      Yeah! Found the word. Put in your link.
    end if
  end for
end for
```

Comment: Thank you iWantSimpleLife.   That's what I was looking for!

Comment: Ha ha. Yup... In case this is a school project. Normally I try not to give specific coding answer unless the questioner post codes themselves.